# Shir HaMa'aloth or 'Al Naharoth Bavel on Rosh Hodesh Av?

Tags: bentching, rosh-chodesh-new-month, nine-days

When Bentching on Rosh Hodesh Av, do you say Shir HaMa'aloth for Rosh Hodesh or 'Al Naharoth Bavel for the Nine Days?

Comment: What do you mean by "'Al Naharoth Bavel for the Nine Days"? Isn't "_Al naharos Bavel_" said *every* day (except festive days) by those who say it? Can you source saying it specifically in the nine days?

Comment: I've only ever said it during the Nine Days. In camp we sang it then, but not the rest of session. I was never taught in school to sing it either (I don't usually sing Bentching as an adult, but that is how I was taught as a child which parts and what Nusah my family says).

Comment: @msh210 I too have seen such a custom. No source though.

Comment: SethJ, @DoubleAA, I know the same practice from summer camp also. I've never heard of any source for it, though, and I assume it was done as a nod to the year-round custom to recite "_Al naharos Bavel_", done specifically then so as to set the somber mood for the campers. (Note that in the practice I know from camp, the entire psalm was not recited: parts of it were.) I wonder there really is a (valid) custom to recite it only during the nine days; absent real evidence of such, I'd assume not.

Comment: @msh210, [you know what to do](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: תדיר ושאינו תדיר - תדיר קודם?

Comment: @HachamGabriel That's a good answer if you want to say _both_ chapters of tehillim.

Comment: @DoubleAA why would you say both?

Comment: @HachamGabriel I don't know, but Tadir is a principle or ordering not of triage. So it would only be applicable if you ruled to say both.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, in fact, Double AA is correct. Tadir _only_ applies when you have two practices to follow and need to set priority of order. In fact, we generally say that the less common practice is the one followed if only two practices are in direct conflict and only one can be followed. The question, if this is relevant to that discussion, would be which is Tadir? Shir HaMa'aloth or 'Al Naharoth Bavel? (Although I'm not sure that is the discussion here; I think it is more, which is more appropriate to the mood of the day, and which supersedes the other. But I concede I may be wrong.)

Comment: possibly relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14589/759

Answer (score -2):

I once saw a bentcher that said that "our minhag" is never to say Al Naharoth Bavel before bentching except at the Seudah Hamafseket before Tisha B'Av. It makes sense because if you only will have one opportunity to say something, then you will have much greater kavanah for it.

Cf. Before the Mishnah on Brachos 34a on the punishment for someone who thinks that multiple opportunities exist to say Shema in the Zman (if there was a chisaron in kavanah). The punishment is that you hit him with a hammer until he has kavanah!

Comment: Is Kavanah the underlying issue here?

Comment: I can't put too much stock in "I once saw a bentcher". What bentcher was it?

Comment: @msh210 - Don't remember. Why should it make a difference? Eizehu chacham, halomeid mikol haadam - including the redactor of the halachos printed in that bentcher.

Comment: @SethJ - Good question. No, not necessarily.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, to say _lomed mikol adam_ means accepting everything everyone tells you as correct is nonsense.

Comment: @msh210, I'll take Adam on his word on that point. It doesn't mean I'll accept it as Halachically binding without knowing the source of the statement "our Minhag is 'X'", but I see no reason to discount that statement out of hand just because the Bentcher in question is not identified. However, a source _would_ be very useful.

Comment: @msh210, on your second point (posted 45 seconds ago), I agree.